# How to display the alert box using selenium ?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert, selenium-ide

Need to display the alert box and click OK while running the script. 
I have used javascript alerts.

Eg:

```
function validateMob(val) {
   var temp = val.trim();

   if (temp == null || temp == "") {
     alert("Enter Mobile Number");
     return false;
   } else if (temp.length != 10) {
     alert("Enter Valid Mobile Number");
     return false;
   } 
   else {
     return true;
   } 
}
```

Also have used to verify the text in the alert box

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String text=alert.getText();
alert.accept();
```

Need to display the alert box and click OK. Is it not possible to view the alert box using selenium web driver ?

Comment: What is the problem? To "view" something in selenium is not very specific...

Comment: What you want to achive? Can you be specific? Is this related to selenium IDE?